# Broken sudo on Google Compute Engine

Tags: centos, sudo, google-compute-engine

**Error :**

```
[ri@myinstance-1 etc]$ sudo su -
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 120 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 120
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

**Planned :**

- The default version of ffmpeg is `ffmpeg version 0.6.5` but we required newest version of ffmpeg in order to proceed `flac to mp4 conversion`.
- But unknowingly  we have installed new version of ffmpeg in `dev@myinstance-1` but our django development server running on `ri@myintance-1`,

**Tried :**

- I know root permission of `sudo alias ffmpeg='/home/dev/bin/ffmpeg'` not working in my login as `ri@myinstance-1`
- So we tried to edit root sudoers file like `ri ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` for grant `root` access to `ri@myinstance-1` after save we can't able to login to root and everything seems broken.

Updated :

- I tried to login with Compute engine ssh terminal but i can't able to connect.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Can we see a copy of your `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: @f01 nooo.! that's the problem... even i can't able to issue `sudo /etc/sudoers` command. Result is above error only ...

Comment: Nope.. same result.

Comment: I guess you edited `/etc/sudoers` and screwed up the syntax. For the future, always edit it with `visudo` — **never** edit it with any other editor that does not check the syntax before saving.

Comment: @slhck yes .. i edited with VI.. actually i never knew about visudio  ..below ans seems very hard for me.. but   i solved this issue with create new instance with snapshot. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can answer your own question to provide a solution for others who have the same issue. (And yes, unfortunately setting up a new system is often the easiest path…)

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your options is mount the disk with the rootfs in another machine and edit `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Are we talking about Remote disk? this is not local disk. Problem in google cloud compute engine...

Comment: Maybe you have this kind of disk in GCE https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks

Comment: ss i have `Standard Persistent Disk` can you please clarify .. how to achieve this ?

Comment: or i have snapshot taken two weeks agao shall i using that to restore previous state?

Comment: Yes you can also do that or here's a hint `gcloud compute instances {detach,attach}-disk` from https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks

Comment: after detach.. what should i do ?

Comment: i can't unmount disk bcse i can't issue sudo here

Comment: May i know this error `- Hot-remove of the root disk is not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

*mistake* is I modified `/etc/sudoers` with `vi` editor instead of `visudo` thanks `@slhck` for pointing that.

I didnt tried  `@f01` answer because that also required to create new compute instance. So i decided to `create new compute instance with old snapshot`.. Problem solved.